# Java can't find classes in parent package

Tags: java

I'm not sure if this is a classpath problem, a syntax problem, or an access modifier problem. I'm trying to implement packages for the first time in Java and having with the compiler not finding classes in the parent package.

I understand there isn't any hierarchical relationship in package structures and I am explicitly importing parent package classes in the child package class.

The parent package classes' constructors are public.

I am under the impression both directories need to be on the classpath but not sure about it. Either way, I have both dirs on the classpath to be sure.

**Directory Structure**

```
home
|
|---java
    |
    |---src
        |
        |---com
            |
            |---inv
                |
                |---mail
                    |
                    |---SendMail.java
                |
                |---TeradataCon.java
                |
                |---ExcelWriter.java
```

**CLASSPATH**

```
(mdexter@server) /home/mdexter/java/src/com/inv/mail # echo $CLASSPATH
.:/storage/mdexter/java/lib/*:/usr/java6_64/jre/lib/*:/usr/java6_64/lib/*:/home/mdexter/java/src/com/inv/*:/home/mdexter/java/src/com/inv/mail/*
```

**SendFile.java (stripped down)**

```
package com.inv.mail;

import com.inv.TeradataCon;
import com.inv.ExcelWriter;

public class SendMail
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TeradataCon teradata = new TeradataCon(some, args, here);
        ExcelWriter xls = new ExcelWriter(some, args, here);
    }
}
```

**TeradataCon.java (stripped down)**

```
package com.inv;

public class TeradataCon
{
    public TeradataCon()
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

**ExcelWriter.java (stripped down)**

```
package com.inv;

public class ExcelWriter
{
    public ExcelWriter()
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

**Error output**

```
(mdexter@server) /home/mdexter/java/src/com/inv/mail # javac *.java
StrategyVolumes.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TeradataCon
location: package com.inv
import com.inv.TeradataCon;
              ^
StrategyVolumes.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ExcelWriter
location: package com.inv
import com.inv.ExcelWriter;
              ^
StrategyVolumes.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TeradataCon
location: class com.inv.mail.StrategyVolumes
                TeradataCon teradata = new TeradataCon(
                ^
StrategyVolumes.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TeradataCon
location: class com.inv.mail.StrategyVolumes
                TeradataCon teradata = new TeradataCon(
                                           ^
StrategyVolumes.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ExcelWriter
location: class com.inv.mail.StrategyVolumes
                ExcelWriter xls = new ExcelWriter(;
                ^
StrategyVolumes.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ExcelWriter
location: class com.inv.mail.StrategyVolumes
                ExcelWriter xls = new ExcelWriter(;
                                      ^
6 errors
```

**What I have tried**

- import com.inv.*; (Shouldn't matter right?)
- Compiled parent classes from /home/java/src/com/inv - works
- Compiled mail/*.java from /home/java/src/com/inv - doesn't work

Comment: Well have you compiled `ExcelWriter` beforehand? Generally you would compile from the `src` directory, with `javac -d ../bin com/inv/mail/*.java` for example.

Comment: And the easiest and safest way is to always compile everything at once. Learning how javac works is a good thing, but once you have understood that, a real build tool like gradle is a must-have.

Comment: Yes - I have compiled inv/java.* beforehand. OK - yes, I would definitely like to be able to compile all classes in com at once, that would be preferable. Will try this. Unfortunately Ant/Gradle etc. is not an option in my case, at least to my knowledge but I'll investigate that more too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the classpath, for starters. You don't put package directories on the classpath - you only put the *root* of output directories there.

I suggest you compile from the `src` directory, with the output going to a `bin` or classes directory. For example, get rid of your `CLASSPATH` environment variable entirely (it's rarely useful, IME - better to specify it as a command-line option where necessary) and then use something like:

```
/home/mdexter/java/src # javac -d ../bin com/inv/mail/*.java
```

Or better, compile everything together, as JB Nizet suggests:

```
/home/mdexter/java/src # javac -d ../bin `find . -name '*.java'`
```

(Or use an IDE and/or build tool.)

Comment: Great, compilation went perfectly! So all that headache over the classpath was not necessary. Now I'm trying to get SendMail to run, but Java gives: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SendMail (wrong name: com/inv/mail/SendMail)" - does this mean I have to rename the class public com.inv.mail.SendMail {} now that it's part of a package? Edit - no nevermind, it won't compile that way..

Comment: @MattDexter: No, that means you need to run it as `java -cp ../bin com.inv.mail.SendMail`

Comment: Ah, and that is where the classpath comes into play, which you define on the fly as the root (bin) with the -cp flag. I get it. Very cool